# Не могу извлечь данные из БД

Tags: golang

Нужна помощь в извлечение данных из БД ms sql и добавление их в БД pg.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"


    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
// конфиг для подключения к ms sql server

// конфиг для подключения к PostgreSQL

)


func main() {
    // Покдлючение к БД ms sql
    connStringmssql := fmt.Sprintf("server=%s;user id=%s;password=%s;port=%d;database=%s;", server, user, password, port, database)
    db, err := connect("mssql", connStringmssql)
    checkError("Error function connect mssql ", err)
    defer db.Close()
    defer fmt.Printf("Disconnected mssql!\n")

    // Покдлючение к БД postgres
    connStringpg := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s", serverpg, portpg, userpg, passwordpg, databasepg, "disable")
    dbpg, err := connect("postgres", connStringpg)
    checkError("Error function connect pg ", err)
    defer dbpg.Close()
    defer fmt.Printf("Disconnected pg!\n")

    // Чтение sql запроса из файла и его конвертация
    mssqlSelectQueryUnConvert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./sql/mssqlSelect.sql")
    checkError("Error read sql file", err)
    mssqlSelectQuery := string(mssqlSelectQueryUnConvert)

    rows, err := db.Query(mssqlSelectQuery)
    checkError("Error sql query ", err)
    defer rows.Close()
    columnNames, err := rows.Columns()
    checkError("Error sql columns names ", err)

    objects := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    objectsScan := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    rest := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    for i := range objects {
        objectsScan[i] = &objects[i]
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(objectsScan...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to scan row", err)
            return
        }
        rest = append(rest, objects...)
    }
    fmt.Println(rest)

    dbInsert, err := dbpg.Exec("INSERT INTO object_test (column1...column18) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18)", rest...)
    checkError("Error dbpg insert ", err)
    fmt.Println(dbInsert.RowsAffected())
}
```

При запуске этого всего выходит ошибка:
Error dbpg insert pq: got 54 parameters but the statement requires 18

Где я ошибся?
Спасибо.

Comment: В каком месте вылетает ошибка?

Comment: на месте вставки

Comment: Так вроде бы же в ошибке довольно чётко сказано, что в `rest` 54 элемента , вместо 18.

Comment: это я понимаю, но я не могу понять как разбить интерфейс на куски по 18 элементов

Comment: Почему это не сделать одним insert?

Comment: В это вся и сложность, что я не совсем понимаю как это сделать. В итоге я хочу разделить это все на две функция. Одна select функция, которая выдает этот интерфейс с данными. Вторая insert функция, которая принимает этот интерфейс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что `rest` должен быть типа `[][]interface{}`, а `objects` надо создавать отдельный на каждой итерации. После этого инсертить в цикле. То есть:

```
for rows.Next() {
    // Тут создаём новые objects и objectsScan.
    objects := // ...
    objectsScan := // ...
    err = rows.Scan(objectsScan...)
    // Check err.
    // Без "...", потому что у нас [][]interface{}
    rest = append(rest, objects)
}

stmt, err := dbpg.Prepare(`INSERT ...`)
// Check err.
defer stmt.Close()
for _, col := range rest {
    _, err = stmt.Exec(col...)
    // Check err.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло